# 'Permission Denied' when attempting to run sh script as part of setuid bit Lesson

Tags: linux, centos

I am attempting to follow through with a lesson on setuid bits and have done the following on a CentOS 7 VM (via Terminal.app on my Mac):

1. create user adam & `program.sh` file in his home folder
2. `program.sh` is a basic script that contains:

   ```
   echo "This is a test" >> /etc/stickytestfile.txt
   ```
3. set `chmod 777` as well as `chmod u+s` to `program.sh` and `/usr/bin/sh`

but I still get 'Permission denied'.  How should I proceed?

```
-bash-4.2$ whoami
adam
-bash-4.2$ ls -al
total 32
drwsrwxrwx. 2 adam adam 4096 Oct  7 17:44 .
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root   58 Oct  7 15:30 ..
-rw-------. 1 adam adam  853 Oct  7 19:26 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--. 1 adam adam   18 Nov 20  2015 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--. 1 adam adam  193 Nov 20  2015 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--. 1 adam adam  231 Nov 20  2015 .bashrc
-rw-rw-r--. 1 adam adam   29 Oct  7 16:07 adampersonalfile
-rw-rw-r--. 1 adam adam   27 Oct  7 16:07 adamsharedfile
-rwsrwxrwx. 1 root root   50 Oct  7 17:44 program.sh
-bash-4.2$ whereis sh
sh: /usr/bin/sh /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz
-bash-4.2$ ls -al /usr/bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4 Oct  2 16:05 /usr/bin/sh -> bash
-bash-4.2$ su
Password:
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8): No such file or directory
[root@localhost adam]# chmod u+s /usr/bin/sh
[root@localhost adam]# ls -al /usr/bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4 Oct  2 16:05 /usr/bin/sh -> bash
[root@localhost adam]# exit
exit
-bash-4.2$ sh program.sh
program.sh: line 1: /etc/stickytest.txt: Permission denied
```

Comment: [Please do not post text as images. Copy-paste the text.](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the INVOCATION section of [the bash man page, bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html):

>   If the shell is started
>     with the effective user (group) id not equal to the real user (group) id,
>     and the
>   **-p**
>   option is not supplied, …,
>     and
>   ***the effective user id is set to the real user id***
>   . 
>     If the
>   **-p**
>   option is supplied at invocation,
>     the startup behavior is the same, but the effective user id is not reset.
>
> (Emphasis added.)

If you run bash without the **`-p`** option,
if it is running setuid (effective user id not equal to the real user id),
it immediately “drops privileges”; i.e., reverts to your real identity.

By the way, you’re using the wrong terminology. 
The bit you’re talking about is the setuid bit, not the sticky bit.

P.S. I hope the instructions you are following tell you
to be sure to set determine bash’s initial mode (permissions bits)
and to restore it when you’re done.

Comment: Hi yes I'm talking about the setuid bit.  Hmm the video tutorials never showed the use of -p option. perhaps I'll try that. I have no idea what 'bash's initial mode' is . I'll check on that. Thanks!

Comment: I mean, if you had done `ls -l /usr/bin/bash` before doing the `chmod`, you would have seen that it was `-rwxr-xr-x` (i.e., 755), and you should change it back to that. `chmod u-s` *should* work, but it would have been better to see what it was originally, so you can explicitly change it back to that. It would have been even better to copy `bash` to `bash.tmp`, then `chmod u+s bash.tmp`, and delete `bash.tmp` when you're done with it.